# selecting date from range not selecting next month

Tags: mysql, date

[image]

This is my data in database.

```
:start = 2017-01-13
:end = 2017-02-13
```

This is my parameter

```
:start <= DATE(date) AND DATE(date) <= :end
```

This is my where clause

I am expecting to get dates between `2017-01-13` and `2017-02-13`

But right now i am getting only date from `2017-01-13` to `2017-01-20`

I am assuming it does not get next month.

How to correctly get dates between two dates

**Update**

[image]

This is what i get when i use

```
(date BETWEEN :start AND :end)
```

I still dont get the dates when the month is `2` february

echo `2017-01-13-----2017-02-13` means

```
echo $periodfrom; --> :start
echo "-----";
echo $periodto; --> :end
```

**Screen shot of data structure for date field**

[image]

Comment: you have use both place <=   you should use :start <= DATE(date) AND DATE(date) >= :end

Comment: `WHERE date BETWEEN :start AND :end`

Comment: @YourCommonSense i tried it but same result only until `2017-01-20`

Comment: @krishnpatel tried it no result for your query

Comment: ohh sorry :start >= DATE(date) AND DATE(date) <= :end

Comment: @YourCommonSense why it is not selecting the dates in february i like your solution it works really good. it gets dates in between but not next month though

Comment: what is the field type?

Comment: type of field is date @YourCommonSense

Comment: then it should select next month as well

Comment: @YourCommonSense can you add it as answer so i can accept it?